# The conflict between the DataTable filter and the calendar picker in Primefaces

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, calendar

I am using JavaEE 7, Primefaces 5.2 and GlassFish 4.1 build 13.

I have a problem to use the DataTable filter and a calendar picker together. In the page, there is a data table which have filters for each column. A separated calendar picker is used to update the data table (Anything after the selected date will be displayed).  The calendar picker works fine if no column filter has been used. However, the calendar picker stop to update the data table if one of the column filters is used. There is no error found either in the log or though the debug.

The related code in the page is:

```
    <h:form>
        <p:outputLabel styleClass="header-calendar">From Date: </p:outputLabel>
        <p:calendar id="fromDate" value="#{datedCarFilterView.fromDate}" pattern="dd MM yyyy"  readonlyInput="true" maxdate="#{datedCarFilterView.currentDate}">
            <p:ajax event="dateSelect" update="viewDataTable" />
        </p:calendar><br/>   
        <p:dataTable var="car" value="#{datedCarFilterView.cars}" id="viewDataTable">

            <p:column headerText="ID">
                <h:outputText value="#{car.id}" />
            </p:column>
            <p:column filterBy="#{car.color}" headerText="Color" filterMatchMode="contains">
                <h:outputText value="#{car.color}" />
            </p:column>    
            <p:column headerText="Date">
                <h:outputText value="#{car.date}">
                    <f:convertDateTime pattern="dd-MMM-yyyy" />
                </h:outputText>
            </p:column>                  
        </p:dataTable>
    </h:form>
```

And the related Java code is as following:

```
@ManagedBean @ViewScoped public class DatedCarFilterView implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 978770613134439198L;

private Date fromDate;

private List<DatedCar> allCars;
private final List<DatedCar> cars = new ArrayList<>();

@ManagedProperty("#{datedCarService}")
private DatedCarService service;

@PostConstruct
public void init() {
    allCars = service.createCars(100);
    fromDate = new Date(getCurrentDate().getTime() - 1000 * 3600 * 24 * 3);
    refreshCarList(fromDate);
}

public void setService(DatedCarService service) {
    this.service = service;
}

public List<DatedCar> getCars() {
    return cars;
}

public Date getFromDate() {
    return fromDate;
}

public void setFromDate(Date fromDate) {
    this.fromDate = fromDate;
    refreshCarList(fromDate);
}

private void refreshCarList(Date fromDate1) {
    cars.clear();
    for (DatedCar car : this.allCars) {
        if (car.getDate().getTime() > fromDate1.getTime()) {
            cars.add(car);
        }
    }
}

public Date getCurrentDate() {
    return new Date();
} }
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that the filter is still in the using state even after its usage. The clearance code needs to be called before another related external action can be performed correctly. The following code change will make it work:

```
<p:ajax event="dateSelect" update="viewDataTable" onstart="PF('vtWidget').clearFilters()"/>
```

and

```
<p:dataTable var="car" value="#{datedCarFilterView.cars}" id="viewDataTable" widgetVar="vtWidget">
```